# how to fix the WMV decoder filter in VMR 9?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, video, video-player

everyone. please help me.
I am using VRM 9 to play wmv video in a win32 application.
The source(C++) I am using is from a resigned coworker, so I could not ask him.
I do not know much about video player in win32 application. total noob. sorry about that.

The application plays wmv video fine, when the preferred DirectShow decoding filter of WMV3 is set to "Microsoft".
However, the application crashes when the preferred DirectShow decoding filter of WMV3 is set to "ffdshow".

There is only one VMR9 filter in the graph. and no configuration of VRM9 filter is related to decoder in the source.

**Here is my question, is there anyway to force DirectShow to use "Microsoft" decoder for WMV3 format?**

I would like to post the source code, but I can't. really sorry about that.
I have been searching MSDN the whole day, but have no idea how to do it.

appreciate any help. thank you.

Comment: Why can't you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: do you build the directshow graph on your own? if yes, just insert your preferred decoder becore inserting the reader, then render the output pin... There are other options how to get to your goal but first i need to know more about what level of control you have about your graph and second i recommend not to use directshow whenever possible.